# Creating a bimodal distribution to equal sum in column vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution

I am trying to generate a column vector (nx1) in Matlab whose values have a bimodal distribution. I want all the values in the column vector to sum to one specified value as well as being able to specify the minimum and the maximum values in the distribution.

Thanks!

Comment: @m7913d I have been trying to work with this uniform distribution example, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9700-random-vectors-with-fixed-sum, however the part I am struggling with is bimodal distribution. There does not seem to be any documentation of people generate bimodal distributions in matlab, only checking if arrays are bimodal distributions. The only way I can think of is using the actual function for bimodal distribution (with the two exp() for the peaks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bimodal distribution is a distribution with two peaks, f.e the superposition of two normal distributions:

```
n = 100;
X = 1:n;
PDF = normpdf(X, 30, 5) + 5*normpdf(X, 60, 10); % take the combination of two normal distrubtions
PDF = PDF/sum(PDF); % normalise it, i.e. sum equals to one.

figure
plot(X, PDF); % plot the result
```

[image]